# Swagger API - no api definition provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

[image: no api definition provided]

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API Name", Version = "v1" });
});
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseSwaggerUi3();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API Name V1");
});
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

,
This is my Program.cs class for my .Net Core MVC structure. I have some API for testing but i cant reach them on Swagger.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApplicationAPIController : ControllerBase
    {
        readonly IApplicationService applicationService;
        readonly IMapper mapper;

        public ApplicationAPIController(IApplicationService applicationService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.applicationService = applicationService;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }
        [HttpGet("GetList")]
        public IActionResult GetList()
        {
            var result = applicationService.GetList();
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(mapper.Map<List<Application>>(result.Data));
            }
            return BadRequest(result.Message);
        }
```

This is my API class for application but i can't reach on Swagger, i don't know where i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of them is the source of the problem.

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```